# Center and outline a div in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following snippet:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  div(
    id = "login",
    align="center",
    textInput("text_login", "Enter your username", ""),
    actionButton("btn_login", "Enter"),
    hidden(verbatimTextOutput("value"))
  ),
  # rest of the code
```

How can I position this div in the center of the page (both vertically and horizontally) and put it inside a rectangular outline, so that it stands out from the rest of the page?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS in shiny apps and tags (like `div`).
I found the `style` [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp).

```
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(
    textInput("text_login", "Enter your username", ""),
    actionButton("btn_login", "Enter",style='margin-bottom:20px;'),
    hidden(verbatimTextOutput("value")),
    style='
      margin: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a good starting point. Do you know how can I insert a small space between `actionButton("btn_login", "Enter")` and `hidden(verbatimTextOutput("value"))` in my div?

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you mean, but I updated the code in the answer to contain your UI elements, with an added style for the button `margin-bottom:20px;`.

Comment: you should look into using CSS with shiny [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).